# Can't deploy to firebase . Get ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, npm, firebase

Every time i run firebase deploy i get the following error

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/joseph/tmp/11484-12736-1f3kttw.tar.gz'
```

Any ideas on what could be causing it?

Comment: You mention you don't have a /home/joseph/tmp directory, but does the user you're running as have permissions to create /home/joseph/tmp ?

Comment: @zouzouek welcome to the StackOverflow community! We'll need a lot more detail than a 3 line error before we can help you here. Check out the guide on [creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 7):

Apparently adding an empty tmp directory to the home folder fixed the issue. Running the command as root doesn't create the directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

The question has inadequate details but it seems that the file `/home/joseph/tmp/11484-12736-1f3kttw.tar.gz` either doesn't exists or it isn't accessible by your running application.

Comment: No details to add, deploying to firebase is as easy as running `firebase deploy `. The only output i get is the above and i don't have a /tmp directory in my home folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo firebase deploy
```

That should do it!