# Unable to do Firebase deploy - Error: Invalid Firebase specified

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

After accomplishing all the necessary steps on [firebase.com/docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/deploying.html) and upgrading my app to newer version I still can't run the deploy it using `firebase-tools`.

**$ firebase deploy MY_APP_NAME**

Gives following stack:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/myusername/.config/configstore/update-notifier-firebase-tools.json'
You don't have access to this file.

at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:34:17)
at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:123:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase:5:48)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
```

Reading this [Can't deploy to firebase . Get ENOENT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668744/cant-deploy-to-firebase-get-enoent-error) I've tried to apply sudo, that helped a bit more - and following: **$ sudo firebase deploy**

after a noticeable pause of 3-5 seconds results in

```
Error: Invalid Firebase specified.

Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help
```

However doing: **$ sudo firebase list**

shows that the project exists:

```
┌────────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Name                   │ Project ID / Instance │ Permissions │
├────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ MY_APP_NAME (current)  │ MY_APP_NAME           │ Owner
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

I have NPM 3.8.6 @ Node v6.0.0 @ Mac 10.11

Comment: After doing the above, I needed to log out and back in on the CLI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, fixing your permissions error is fairly simple:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/configstore
```

Then, to deploy the command is

```
firebase deploy --project MY_PROJECT_ID
```

Where MY_PROJECT_ID is the first entry in the 'Project ID / Instance' column of the `firebase list` table. Check out `firebase use --help` command to set the default project for a directory

Comment: I'm having the same issue where I'm only using Firebase's hosting features. I've tried `firebase deploy`, `firebase deploy --only hosting`, and even `firebase deploy --project 'project-name'` (which should be needed when in the project's directory). None of them work with Firebase 3.0.

Comment: BTW, I have upgraded to latest npm version of firebase-tools and I have "imported" the old firebase repo to a shiny new one ... `firebase init` recognized it. Just can't deploy to it!

Comment: @ken have u been able to figure it out? Dealing with the same issue as well

Comment: Well for me, I actually just had to return to the repo 24 hours later and whatever was causing the problem -- which must have been on the server side of the API interaction -- was fixed. Good luck @user2202911, hope you get to the bottom of your problem.

Comment: @ken thanks for your reply. I just went ahead and created a new firebase project and copy + pasted my code.  Thankfully I'm still in development for my project so I'm ok with starting with a new database

Answer (score 30):

I've recently encountered this problem suddenly while trying to deploy to production it just suddenly shows this message and trying above methods didn't work.

Here's what worked on mine.

First I logged out my firebase account by:

```
firebase logout
```

then logged in again

```
firebase login
```

then just reselect the project

```
firebase use project_name
```

and I can now deploy properly without the problem reoccurring again.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting this anyone message even though I was logged in correctly and the project existed: "Failed to get Firebase project xxxxx. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it". Login out and back in did it.

Answer (score 6):

As [Chris Raynor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937583/chris-raynor) mentioned, first fix your permission problem with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/configstore
```

My upgrade resulted in the same error ("Invalid Firebase specified"). I found that clearing and re-adding the project solved my problem.

I ran the commands below, after migrating to the new version of firebase and following the initial interactive process.

```
firebase use --clear

firebase use --add
```

The "add" option gave me the following interactive prompts:

```
? Which project do you want to add? my-project-name
? What alias do you want to use for this project? (e.g. staging) staging
```

After clearing and re-adding, my deploy command worked according to the documentation

```
firebase deploy
```

The final working output looked like this:

```
i  deploying database, hosting
i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...
✔  hosting: 34 files uploaded successfully
i  starting release process (may take several minutes)...

✔  Deploy complete!
```

Answer (score 5):

I've faced the same issue (**Invalid Firebase Specified**) when imported project from old firebase dashboard to their newer console, and fixed it using the following terminal commands,

> `firebase use --clear`
>   //Clear any previous project selection for firebase-tools
>
> `firebase use --add`
>   // Add the newly imported project with a new alias

After clearing and re-adding the project with an alias, i was able to deploy it successfully using

> `firebase deploy`.